# How do I get tap locations (GestureDetector)?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to implement double-tap-to-zoom in my [zoomable_images plugin](https://github.com/perlatus/flutter_zoomable_image/blob/3515144d1ce43d7363258ef51e3d4c7e4e1c22ab/lib/src/zoomable_image.dart#L120) but the [GestureTapCallback](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/GestureTapCallback.html) doesn't provide the tap location information.

Ideally the offset would be returned by the callback. Is there another API for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can provide a [`GestureTapDownCallback`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/GestureTapDownCallback.html) callback as the [`onTapDown`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/MultiTapGestureRecognizer/onTapDown.html) argument of the [`GestureDetector`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) constructor. The `GestureTapDownCallback` takes a [`TapDownDetails`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/TapDownDetails-class.html) argument that includes the global position of the tap. You can then convert it to relative coordinates using [`BuildContext.findRenderObject`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findRenderObject.html) and [`RenderBox.globalToLocal`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderBox/globalToLocal.html):

```
Offset _tapPosition;

void _handleTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
  final RenderBox referenceBox = context.findRenderObject();
  setState(() {
    _tapPosition = referenceBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new GestureDetector(
     /* ... */
     onTapDown: _handleTapDown,
  );
}
```

In your `onDoubleTap` handler, you can reference `_tapPosition` to find out where the most recent tap was located.

For an example of this in action, see [`InkWell`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/ink_well.dart).

Comment: I'm not getting the `onTapDown` events when I have a non-null `onDoubleTap` handler. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: You know what, you're totally right -- there's no way to get the location of a double-tap, and there should be. I filed https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10048 to track this.

Answer (score 0):

### as of `[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3)`

```dart
GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (details) {

        var position = details.globalPosition;
        // you can also check out details.localPosition; 

        if (position.dx < MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2){
          // tap left side
        } else {
          // tap rigth size
        }
      },
      child: SomeChildWidget(),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle **double taps**, you'll need to store the tap position from the `onDoubleTapDown` and then work with `onDoubleTap`:

```
late Offset _doubleTapPosition;
...
onDoubleTap: () {
    //do your stuff with _doubleTapPosition here
},
onDoubleTapDown: (details) {
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    _doubleTapPosition = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
},
```

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63228704/get-details-on-doubletap-on-flutter-gesturedetector)